# Internet Connection Sharing via SLIP

Tags: windows-xp, serial-port, serial, amiga

I'm trying to get my Amiga 2000 online with a serial cable connected to a PC running Windows XP. I'm following [these instructions](http://www.amigaforever.com/kb/13-106), which glance over how exactly to configure Internet Connection Sharing with SLIP.

As you can see, I'm sharing my wireless connection. I set up a new "Incoming" connection, listening on COM1. I don't know if that is necessary.

[image: Internet Connection Sharing]

I am certain my serial cable is functioning properly, because I have sent data to the Amiga with ADF Sender (adfsender.stoeggl.com/).

If anyone has successfully shared their network over a serial cable, whatever OS you used on your host box, please let me know. I haven't tried this with Linux, yet, but that is my next step. I just assumed it would be easier in Windows.

**EDIT:**
**I set up a SLIP connection from Windows over my serial cable. Whenever I start to dial, then ping *any* address from the Amiga except `192.168.0.2` (the Amiga's IP) the ping requests show up in the pre-dial terminal on Windows. They all fail with 100% packet loss.**

[image: Terminal]

Comment: I found a thread on lemonamiga.com where people are discussing this very issue: http://www.lemonamiga.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6521

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working under Linux... [This blog](http://wnd.katei.fi/amiga/network.html) showed me how to get the serial connection set up on my PC, then I consulted [some Gentoo documentation](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/home-router-howto.xml) on setting up DNS and NAT.